# SPRING MVC - How to get the value of form:input path from JSP to Controller

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC and I'm having this problem where I wanted to get the value of form:input path and pass it to my controller.

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3465813074586302847L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int empId;

@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String email;

@Column
private String address;

@Column
private String telephone;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="empUserId")
private EmployeeUserAccount employeeUserAccount;

//setters and getters
```

**EmployeeUserAccount.java**

```
public class EmployeeUserAccount implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3465813074586302847L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int empUserId;

@Column
private String userName;

@Column
private String password;

@Column
private String userLevel;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="employeeUserAccount")
private Employee employee;
```

**EmployeeForm.jsp**

```
<form:form action="saveEmployee" method="post" >
    <table>
        <form:hidden path="empId"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="empUserId" value="${employee.employeeUserAccount.empUserId}"/>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><form:input path="name" value="${employee.name}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><form:input path="email" value="${employee.email}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address:</td>
            <td><form:input path="address" value="${employee.address}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Telephone:</td>
            <td><form:input path="telephone" value="${employee.telephone}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><form:input path="employeeUserAccount.userName" value="${employee.employeeUserAccount.userName}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><form:input path="employeeUserAccount.password"  value="${employee.employeeUserAccount.password}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Role:</td>
            <td>
                <%-- <form:select path="employeeUserAccount.userLevel">
                <form:options />
                </form:select> --%>
                <form:select path="employeeUserAccount.userLevel">
                <c:forEach items="${role}" var="r">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${r==employee.employeeUserAccount.userLevel}">
                            <option value="${r}" selected="true">${r}</option>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <option value="${r}">${r}</option>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command") Employee employee, @RequestParam("empUserId") Integer empUserId) {

    // How to get the employeeUserAccount.userName from path
    // How to get the employeeUserAccount.password from path
```

Comment: is that Employee is your DTO(data transfer object)? only declaring the dto as a parameter will help you to get the values

Comment: What about first passing an Employee object using Model attribute? in order to accomplish data binding. I can't see that in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Some key points:
**1.** Your DTO (`Employee.java`) should contains a default Constructor.
 **2.** Change below code:

```
<form:form action="saveEmployee" method="post" >
```

to:

```
<form:form action="saveEmployee" method="post" commandName="saveRecord">
```

**3.** Change all input fields for-exp:

```
<form:input path="name" value="${employee.name}"/>
```

to

```
<form:input path="name" value="${name}"/>
```

I mean to say change '`employee.fieldName`' to just '`fieldName`'
**4.** Now change your controller's method to according to your form parameters:

```
public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("saveRecord") Employee employee, @RequestParam("empUserId") Integer empUserId) {
//do anything you want
}
```

Comment: Now how can I get the value of username and password from the controller?

Comment: @Makudex, in your case, 'employee.employeeUserAccount.password' in controller will contains the password entered by user.I mean to say employee.getEmployeeUserAccount().getPassword()